# Probability of gaining more than $\$20$ in a two person die game

Tags: probability, dice

> Jack and Jill gamble on a roll of a die, as follows. If the die shows $1$ or $2$ spots, Jack gives Jill $\$1$. If the die shows $5$ or $6$ spots, Jill gives Jack $\$1$. If the die shows $3$ or $4$ spots, no money changes hands. Suppose Jack and Jill play this game $400$ times. The chance that Jill’s net gain is more than $\$20$ is closest to:
>
> a) $10\%$
> b) $20\%$
> c) $30\%$
> d) $40\%$

Addition Rule: $\Pr(A\text{ or }B)= \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$

$$\Pr(\text{Jack 1 or 2}, + \text{\$1 to Jill})=( 1/6)+(1/6)=2/6$$
$$\Pr(\text{Jill 5 or 6, + \$1 to Jack})=(1/6)+(1/6)=2/6$$
$$\Pr(\text{3 or 4; \$0 both Jack & Jill})= (1/6)+(1/6)=2/6$$

$n=400$

$\Pr(\text{net gain >\$20})$?

Comment: Your probabilities are incorrect. First, it should be pretty obvious that $11/6$ is wrong since probabilities are between 0 and 1 inclusive. Note that $P(2) = \dfrac{1}{6}$ (There's only 1 `2 spot` out of 6 spots).

Comment: Using addition rule P(A or B)= P(A)+P(B)?

Comment: I think you are going to need a lot more than the addition rule. This looks to me like you are supposed to use the normal (Gaussian) approximation to the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each game, with probability $1/3$ each, Jill wins $\$1$, loses $\$1$ or plays even. Letting $X_i$ denote the gain of Jill in some game $i$, we have

\begin{align}
E(X_i) &= \frac{1}{3}(1 + 0 + -1) = 0 \\ 
\mathrm{Var}(X_i) &= \frac{1}{3}\left(1^2 + 0^2 + (-1)^2\right) = \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}

Letting $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{400} X_i$ denote the overall profit of Jill in $n = 400$ games, we can compute the mean and variance of $Y$ as follows, using that the $X_i$ are i.i.d.:

\begin{align}
E(Y) &= E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{400} X_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{400} E(X_i) = 0 \\ 
\mathrm{Var}(Y) &= \mathrm{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{400} X_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{400} \mathrm{Var}\left(X_i\right) = 400 \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{800}{3}.
\end{align}

Using the Gaussian approximation, $Y$ can be approximated by a normally distributed random variable $Y'$ with the same mean and variance, i.e, with $Y'$ satisfying $Y' \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 800/3)$. So we finally get an approximation as

$$P(Y > 20) \approx P(Y' > 20) = P\left(Z > \frac{20}{\sqrt{800/3}}\right) \approx P(Z > 1.22474) \approx 0.11034.$$

(Here $Z$ denotes a standard normal random variable, i.e, $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.)

So the answer is closest to (a) $10\%$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of $a$ times \$-1, $b$ times \$0, and $c$ times \$1 is:
$$
\Pr(a, b, c) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{400} \frac{400!}{a!\,b!\,c!} \qquad (a+b+c=400)
$$
The probability to gain more than \$20 is:
$$
\begin{align}
& \sum_{a=0}^{400}\ \sum_{c=21+a}^{400-a}\ \Pr(a,\ 400-a-c,\ c) \\
&=\ \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{400} 400!\ 
\sum_{a=0}^{400}\ \frac{1}{a!}\ \sum_{c=21+a}^{400-a}\ \frac{1}{(400-a-c)!\ c!} \\
&\approx\  0.10
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I like your solution since it avoids the normal approximation, but I'm curious how you reduced the final solution to .10?  I'm guessing you used software just curious. I think it can be bad form to make such a jump like that from summation to numerical result.

Comment: I entered the last formula in Mathematica, like this: `(1/3)^400*400!*
 Sum[1/a!*Sum[1/(400 - a - c)!/c!, {c, 21 + a, 400 - a}], {a, 0, 400}]`